# Terraform import aws_cloudwatch_log_stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I need to import an existing `aws_cloudwatch_log_stream` (or `AWS::Logs::LogStream` in CloudFormation) into my configuration. However, [it appears that Terraform does not support this functionality](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_log_stream.html). CloudFormation also doesn't support this functionality, so I can't just wrap it into a mini CloudFormation template.

I don't want to delete and remake my old log stream.

What should I do? What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality was added in [version 2.67.0 of the AWS provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/d274ceceaf6f91e4e7a0ab8b096c7a3b86d70ee5/CHANGELOG.md#2670-june-19-2020).

You should be able to import a log stream when using that version or greater by running the following command:

```
terraform import aws_cloudwatch_log_stream.foo Yada:SampleLogStream1234
```

---

Original answer:

[This pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/13697) was raised today and will add the ability to import Cloudwatch Log Streams in the form of `logGroup:logStream`. The documentation provides an example:

```
terraform import aws_cloudwatch_log_stream.foo Yada:SampleLogStream1234
```

To be able to use this you can either wait for it to be merged (likely very soon as it's small and the author has contributed a lot to the AWS provider) and then released or you can build the provider yourself from [the pull request's forked repo and branch](https://github.com/ewbankkit/terraform-provider-aws/tree/f-aws_cloudwatch_log_stream-import).